# 404 error 'document not found' for JavaScript file when Installing Instafeed onto Wordpress site

Tags: javascript

I uploaded the file `instafeed.min.js` to my websites server.

I then added the `Instafeed script` to the very end of the `<body>`.

This is the exact script:

```
<script src="http://www.carolinewhitephotography.com
          /wp-admin/js/instafeed.min.js?ver=4.4" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var feed = new Instafeed ({
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'awesome',
        clientId: 'my-id',
template: '<a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>'
 });
    feed.run();
</script>
```

Within the page, I have added this, as the directions say to:

```
<div id="instafeed"></div>
```

Nothing shows up on the page. http://www.carolinewhitephotography.com/instagram/

I inspected the element and I get two errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Instafeed is not defined
```

and

```
GET http://www.carolinewhitephotography.com/
                wp-admin/js/instafeed.min.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I contacted my host to check the file root and it is indeed there.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Laura

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you aren't compressing your js files with any other plugin. If you are, that's most probably the case.